# upload file directly from html-form to mariadb table, in a LONGBLOB column, with php

Tags: php, file, mysqli

I try to upload a file from html-form in my mariadb database booksummerytable. I get an db entry in the table, in columns student_id and a book_id, but the file-entry just do not want pass in the LONGBLOB column for the file.

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  if ($_SESSION["rolle"] === "schueler" && isset($_GET['id'])) {
      $buchId = $_GET['id'];

      $dbHost = '...';
      $dbUser = '...';
      $dbPass = '...';
      $dbName = '...';

      $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Verbindung zur Datenbank fehlgeschlagen: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }

      // Wiederholen Sie Ihre Datenbankabfrage, um die Buchinformationen zu erhalten
      $sql = "SELECT title FROM buecher WHERE id = ?";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param("i", $buchId);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->get_result();

      if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
          $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
          $buchtitel = $row['title'];

          // Hier fügen wir das Formular zum Hochladen der Zusammenfassung hinzu
          echo '<h2>Zusammenfassung für das Buch: ' . $buchtitel . '</h2>';
          echo '<form action="upload_zusammenfassung.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
          echo '    <input type="file" name="zusammenfassung" id="zusammenfassung">';
          echo '    <input type="hidden" name="buch_id" value="' . $buchId . '">';
          echo '    <input type="submit" value="Zusammenfassung hochladen">';
          echo '</form>';
      } else {
          echo "Buch nicht gefunden.";
      }

      $stmt->close();
  }
  ?>
```

Anothe file, where happen the db-entry

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

if ($_SESSION["rolle"] === "schueler" && isset($_FILES['zusammenfassung']) && isset($_POST['buch_id'])) {
    // Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
    $dbHost = '...';
    $dbUser = '...';
    $dbPass = '...';
    $dbName = '...';

    $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Verbindung zur Datenbank fehlgeschlagen: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $buchId = $_POST['buch_id'];

    // Dateiinformationen

    $dateiTmpName = $_FILES['zusammenfassung']['tmp_name'];
    $dateiDaten = file_get_contents($dateiTmpName);

    // Schüler-ID aus der Datenbank anhand des Benutzernamens holen
    $schuelerBenutzername = $_SESSION["username"];


    $sqlSchuelerId = "SELECT id_student FROM students WHERE newUsername = ?";
    $stmtSchuelerId = $conn->prepare($sqlSchuelerId);
    $stmtSchuelerId->bind_param("s", $schuelerBenutzername);
    $stmtSchuelerId->execute();
    $stmtSchuelerId->bind_result($schuelerId);
    $stmtSchuelerId->fetch();
    $stmtSchuelerId->close();


        // SQL-Befehl, um die Zusammenfassung in der Datenbank zu speichern
        $sql = "INSERT INTO buchzusammenfassung (idSchueler, idBuch, datei) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("iib", $schuelerId, $buchId, $dateiDaten);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Die Zusammenfassung wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen und in der Datenbank gespeichert.";

        } else {
            echo "Fehler beim Hochladen der Zusammenfassung.";
        }

        $stmt->close();


    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: How many times people should write that it's VERY BAD to upload files in database?

Comment: @SemyonBayandin why?

Comment: I find it more curious that, both of the links used to close this question as duplicate DO NOT AT ALL mention the solution I gave below. Moderators are like: "Oh look! The word BLOB! I saw that on another post! Yep. It's a duplicate!". Hilarious...!

Comment: @RoMan Are you by any chance banned in Google? Because it is a huge overloading for database and server itself. If you one day would want to create a dump of database, just imagine how large it would be. It is much better and safe to keep files in file system as ordinary files, not in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses incorrect data type binding for `LONGBLOB`. The correct type to use is "s" for string when binding binary data.

```php
// Correct the bind_param line to use "s" for binding LONGBLOB data
$stmt->bind_param("iis", $schuelerId, $buchId, $dateiDaten);
```

Comment: yeah thats rigth! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You only really *need* to use the `b`/blob bind in mysqli if the row data you're sending is, in aggregate, larger than your mysql server's configured `max_allowed_packet`. When using this bind type you must set the value to `null` and then use [`mysqli_stmt::send_long_data()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data) like so:

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null);
$fp = fopen("messages.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(0, fread($fp, 8192));
}
fclose($fp);
$stmt->execute();
```

The above example is lifted from the linked doc, but the key points are to bind a null variable, use a chunk size smaller than the configured `max_allowed_packet` [8192 in this example], and call `send_long_data()` as many times as necessary to power through the data.

If you are certain that your data will always be smaller than `max_allowed_packet` then the much simpler answer is to use an `s`/string bind as suggested by @suchislife.